# How to add a subscript character inside an equation

Tags: support, markdown

I want to add something like F<sub>A</sub> (the force at point A.), I've been doing it this way:
$F$<sub>$A$</sub> but inside an equation starting with 2 dollar signs(I want it to be written on a separate line Like:
$$F&lt;sub>A&lt;/sub>$$  this is causing some troubles, and it seems that it couldn't be done this way, so how can I do it?

Comment: There is a pretty good quick reference that covers a lot more than this at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/804/2451

Comment: In general, if you want to know how something like this is done, find a question or answer that does it, and click "edit". Then you will see the source code for the equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Underscore.  `F_A` in TeX is $F_A$.  For longer strings use `{}` groups like `F_{10}`: $F_{10}$

Answer (score 6):

The tool we use for math rendering is called MathJax. It provides a close simulation of LaTeX math-mode. The subscript operator is `_`, so you write `F_A`.